# App Transport Security and IP addresses in iOS9

Tags: ios9

I develop my iOS app using a local server running on my dev box. When testing on devices, I connect directly via an IP address, which is over HTTP and not HTTPS (so I don't have to deal with self-signed certs while in development, which the device wouldn't even like anyways).

I thought that this would be sufficient:

[image]

However,  cannot get it to work without also adding `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = YES`, AKA this:

[image]

Now, I will have to remember to remove this when rolling a production build but not during development...arg. Should the `NSExceptionDomains` work with IP addresses, and if not, is there anything else I can do without also enabling `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Hard-coded IP address wont work in iOS9. I also faced the same issue. 
Tried all permutations & combinations of available solutions.
Finally, had to use a proper domain name.

So, NO.In iOS9 you just can't get away with hard-coded IP addresses.

Comment: I came across this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6205 about allowing IP address on the LAN.  Unfortunately, there is no current solution, but a feature request has been submitted.

Comment: Did anyone find an official documentation stating this? Is this an Apple bug, or is this intended?

Comment: This is intended only, for security purpose. Apple mentioned this during WWDC-2015 http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2015/06/apple-will-require-ipv6-support-for-all-ios-9-apps/

Comment: IP addresses won't work as specified by documentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33 table 2

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  If you disable ATS, connections to IP addresses work just fine.

Comment: @Avi you're right, however, esilver was looking for a workaround that doesn't require disabling ATS otherwise, there is a risk that he forgets when pushing to production.

Comment: Simplest then to just use different info.plist files.  You can have a different info.plist per build type.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32704702/2017049 on how to disable ATS for Debug builds only, allowing IP address for testing.

Answer (score 26):

> is there anything else I can do without also enabling `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`?

One workaround is to use [xip.io](http://xip.io/), as explained by [QJeffR](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/QJeffR) in [this Apple Developer Forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6205#76214) (which was shared by David L in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903923/app-transport-security-and-ip-addresses-in-ios9#comment52969052_31454806)):

> A DNS call to (for example) [10.0.1.8.xip.io](http://10.0.1.8.xip.io) will resolve to [10.0.1.8](http://10.0.1.8), allowing use of the domain instead of the IP address for the `NSExceptionDomains` key.

Comment: This works for those that need to (for various reasons) connect to an IP address instead of a domain name, or to connect to LAN IP addresses.

This also works for LAN addresses, but the iOS must have an internet connection to be able to access the xip.io service.

Then all you need is to allow "xip.io" and subdomains in the App Transport Security Settings.

Comment: Wouldn't this just route all your insecure traffic through an unknown xip.io server?

Comment: DNS calls don't route traffic, they just "map" domain names with ip addresses.

Answer (score 5):

As @PanxShaz said you can't put an hardcoded IP address but you can use an easy workaround:

1. Open your `/etc/hosts` file using `sudo` and add a new local domain name for your ip address.  Example:

   `192.168.99.100    docker-host.localhost`
2. Then flush your DNS :

   `dscacheutil -flushcache`
3. And finally use this new local domain in your app transport security exceptions.

Comment: This is not possible on iOS without jailbreaking.

Comment: @Avi Yes, it is possible, simply because this is actually done on you mac. The purpose here is to offer a workaround when developing.

Comment: Unless your iOS device is using your mac for DNS, it won't work.  Maybe on the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting iOS 10+, just set the [NSAllowsLocalNetworking](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35) flag.