# Add domain exception to App Transport Security ios9

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios9, app-transport-security

I am using following code in my plist to add my server exception to App Transport Security protocol.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>172.16.4.139</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

but it is giving message "**The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.**".

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Actually it is working, i used "ip-api.com" as domain, then it is working fine. But when i am giving local ip of my server it is not accepting it

Comment: try the `NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` and `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion ` -> `TLSv1.1`

Answer (score 2):

> Hard-coded IP address wont work in iOS 9.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454806/5276004).