# App Transport Security policy error while connecting to server with IP address

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app which connects to a server to call APIs using IP address, I don't have a domain associated with it. I have tried following solution in plist.info file, but still i receive same error.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

I want to know how i can escape this security policy in this case, this is our development server , we will associate domain name later while submitting app to store, I want to be able to test and develop.

> NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Comment: You have to disable ATS by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true`.

Comment: @avi please read my post carefully

Comment: If that doesn't work, there's something else going on.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: @avi updated answer with error

Comment: @avi this solution works only for URL with domains

Comment: That is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't use hard coded IP Addresses. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454806/6351482) for more info.

> *Hard-coded IP address wont work in iOS9. I also faced the same issue. Tried all permutations & combinations of available solutions. Finally, had to use a proper domain name.*

Comment: That is a false statement.  I've been using IP addresses for the past several weeks with no issues at all.

Comment: @Avi Can you provide some evidence on how you have been doing that? If it is false then I will remove my answer.

Comment: @avi this thing works with Xcode 6.0 without any issue , even I am using it , but my other machine has Xcode 7.2 and there it fails so it varies SDk to SDK , older SDKs it works, so please be gentle while using down vote

Comment: I am using it with Xcode 7.3.1, base SDK of 9.3.  If you're not current, you should be.