# Swift2.0 HTTP request not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

Hello Stackoverflow,

I keep getting this error after I moved my swift app onto Swift2.0:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

And I took a look at the following link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5835

and added the following code to my info.plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict/>
</dict>
```

And it still doesn't work, anyone have an alternative solution?

Comment: Look at this link @https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4560

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9.

Comment: I tried the second result and it still hasn't worked for me

Comment: Have you tried just allowing all other connection without the NSExceptionDomains key? `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>`

Comment: Yes and that didn't resolve my issue either

Answer (score 8):

Its not a `Swift 2.0` issue its actually an `iOS 9.0` issue where `iOS 9.0` forces web traffic to go over `https` setting the below flag allows `http` traffic.

You have to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Sadly Not working. And it is not ios9 related.