# How do I find out which HTTP requests are being blocked by App Transport Security?

Tags: ios, nsurl, ios9, app-transport-security

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30731785/361247) that I can whitelist domains where I know it will be making non HTTPS requests.

However, after whitelisting a few domains, I noticed that there are still a few requests blocked by `NSURLRequest`, is there a way to find out which domains are being blocked by it?

Answer (score 4):

If you are making the request, modify your connection:didFailWithError: method and print the URL that failed.

If some third-party library is making the request, set the CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS environment variable to 1 (or 2 or 3).

Answer (score -3):

http requests are not blocked, they are automatically turned into https requests. To find out what is blocked, set a breakpoint in your code where  a connection error would be reported.

Comment: Technically true, but if the server doesn't support HTTPS (or if HTTPS provides content for a different domain and doesn't support SNI), the difference is purely academic.

Comment: Thats a function of the server, not the client.