# iOS9 App Transport Security blocked web service with plist modified

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

Run my app on iOS 9 device,
got error logged:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure.  Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

I surely did add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to info.plist:

[image]

It still loaded nothing from the web...
What did I miss?

Do I have to allow the certain domain for my web service ?

Comment: Your code is correct . I had the same problem by adding this code worked . You try to contact another different url

Comment: try to clean the project Shift+Command+K

Comment: @pupboss remove app from my device, clean the project and restart it solved my problem.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. I tried both the blanket "AllowsArbitraryLoads" you used and also tried specifically allowing my domain. I did multiple cleans, restarts, etc, nothing has worked for me so far. Let m know if you figure anything out, and I'll do the same.

Comment: Just be aware that this is a temporary measure to let you get on with developing on iOS 9 until you fixed your resource loading code. When you submit to the App Store, Apple will want a pretty good reason why you are allowing unsafe http everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to fix this query.

Ref->[How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

-> Open Plist File of your project.

-> Then add NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.

-> Then add  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its value to YES.

[image]

Now, Clean your project and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

please add these line in your plist 1- go to plist 2- right click and go to open as -> source code 3- paste these line in source code

Comment: please add  these line in your plist
1- go to plist 
2- right click and go to open as -> source code
3- paste these line in source code