# WebView Xcode 7 blank error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to launch a URL with WebView on xCode 7 and my issue is that it always appears a blank white page when i hit the Build button.

Below is the code:

**ViewConntroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL= @"http://www.google.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; _activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 and iOS 9 introduced a system known as [App Transport Security (ATS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html).
This will prevent the app from loading certain web resources and in a WebView this will lead to a blank screen.

The gist of this is you must choose from one of the following:

**a)** Only use HTTPS resources -> Perhaps try https://www.google.com (not tested this myself).

**b)** Selectively choose which NON-HTTPS resources to use -> See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732693/1086779) for explanation.

**c)** Disable ATS all together -> Not advised, but unavoidable sometimes. To do this, find your Info.plist file and add the following:

NSAppTransportSecurity (Dictionary)
|
----> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads(Bool) = YES

OR in source code view (right click on file > Open As > Source Code):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732693/1086779) for more.

Check the console of Xcode when running the app to see if you get an error message that says you must temporarily white list this site.