# How to by pass ATS for Web Application in ios9

Tags: ios9

Hi we are not using Native Application, we are using web application. Can you please let us know how this can be achieved in Web Application. Is there any code that we need to add to our web config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP you'll need to add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key to your Info.plist, then inside add the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` boolean with the value of `YES`

[image]

It's **not recommended** to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` on the App Store as it will whitelist all insecure HTTP loads.

If you know the HTTP url then it's recommended to add a single exception for that particular domain with the `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` key.

[image]

Better yet, upgrade to HTTPS/SSL without the need to use any ATS exceptions.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Comment: Hi, We are using a Web application not a Native Application. Please tell how this can be achieved for Web Application.

Comment: @vivekanandan.gGanesan is it on the App Store? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Hi It is a web application build for Desktop Machines with Responsive UI. So the same can be used to view in iPhone and iPad. After ios 9 upgrade the application is not getting launched in TEST environment