# NSData cannot retrive image from internet anymore

Tags: ios, image, nsdata

The following code works fine before iOS8.4.1 (includ 8.4.1). While it ruturns nil in iOS9.0.1. Is it a bug or there is a public annoucement for this change? I tested with two iPads.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mapshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/mapshots-ag-studio-agricultural-mapping-software-logo.png")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
NSLog("Data length @%", (data?.length)!)
```

Comment: This question is duplicated. Should I delele it or leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related to ATS(App Transport Security Protocol) changes made by Apple in iOS 9. By default iOS9 disregard communication with `http` protocol. Your URL should be `https`. However you can include exception for specific domains in your app or you can allow all `http` communication to be allowed from within your app.
Check the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) for full details.

To Allow all http domains from your application, you should add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <dict>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      <true/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  </dict>
```

But as Apple has recommended these new settings, you should chose to add exception for this specific domain in your app rather than allowing all `http` domains. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 9 you can't call an HTTP anymore because the ATS (App Transport Security) calls should be HTTPS. To work with HTTP links, you should insert the following key in the info.plist file to disable the ATS:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
     <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
     </dict>
```

create a new voice in the info.plist file "NSAppTransportSecurity" like dict.
insert in it the key "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" like boolean and set to YES

;-)

Comment: Rather than turn it off completely, just add exception for individual domains to the info.plist.

Comment: Yes, exception would be better...