# NSAppTransportSecurity whats this and how should you act?

Tags: ios, xcode

Our latest app got this strange message when tried to send data to local hardware by connecting the iPhone to his network in the wifi settings .

Then i have read you have to add this  `NSAppTransportSecurity` to your plist.

But then i have read here, that this is not safe way, and that you have to enable ssl and enable exception domains .

[How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

So , what is the way to do it ?

Can doing it in my way can cause the iOS to not get back responds ??

Comment: Check this - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820320/nsdata-cannot-retrive-image-from-internet-anymore/32820622#32820622](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820320/nsdata-cannot-retrive-image-from-internet-anymore/32820622#32820622)

Comment: Refer this :--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9