# I am using XCode 7.2. My IOS application only connects to webservices with https Protocol..Why is that?

Tags: ios, xcode

My Code is as below.This code does not work. But the services with https protocol works..Pls help

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let urlPath = "http://xx.com"
            let reposURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            let URLrequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: reposURL)
            let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil
            // 2
            do{
            if let JSONData: NSData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(URLrequest, returningResponse: response){
            //if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
                // 3
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                    // 4
                    if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                        // 5
                        for item in reposArray {

                        }
                    }
               }
            }
            }catch{}
    }
```

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820320/nsdata-cannot-retrive-image-from-internet-anymore/32820622#32820622](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820320/nsdata-cannot-retrive-image-from-internet-anymore/32820622#32820622)

Comment: Not work in the sense the block is not getting called or getting any error?

Comment: Thank you very much.. it worked.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add App Transport Security Settings to your XCode .plist-file:

```
App Transport Security Settings   Dictionary   (1 item)

          Allow Arbitrary Loads   BOOLEAN      YES
```

Official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Also see this source: http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 func jsonParse()
    {
        let urlPath: String = "http://www.airforce.lk/test.php"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil
        do
        {
            let dataVal: NSData =   try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response)
            let json: NSArray =  try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)!
            print("Synchronous\(json)")

            if let json: NSArray = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)
            {
                print(json[0])
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to whitelist this in info.list : <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>