# How to play video in streaming at UIView in iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I am playing video in UIView using AVPlayer after downloading from AWS server with Cognito poolid. But here is a problem that it first download video then it is playing and it is taking some time to download.

I am using Amazon S3 Transfer Utility for uploading and downloading files.

So I need any way that I can play it in stream using url or something direct stream way.

Can anyone please help me some way that I can implement it properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVPlayer wont play video from url in iOS9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865228/avplayer-wont-play-video-from-url-in-ios9)

Comment: Question - can you play video by pasting the video url to browser directly?

Comment: @iphonic, no because cognito doesn't provide url. It provide NSData after download.