# Xcode tableview cell unable display image via url

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I followed the code based on here [tableview Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/) and i did successfully show something in my tableview.

I want to change the cell image by using url link from website.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_126382_400x400.png"];
NSString *path = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"/"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

If I change my str to 
`NSString *str = @"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrKOobbDUVMwrrqMkpvfhITeyQewM8Kj0fZg_X_u3TaM-CLi5QfA";`
then it will successfully change the image of each cell in table view.

Both urls link to the same image but the first link image size is bigger than second link.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7 ? Perhaps `HTTP` URLs are blocked by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: actually u call the synchronous it take some delay

Comment: @GoodSp33d, yes i m using xcode 7. what can i do to unblock it?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, but i did wait for quite long time still no image occurs

Comment: Check that related question in my comment. Here you go : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817873/366346

Comment: scroll once and check the image will appear or ur tableview will get hang else check console HTTP related anything showed

Comment: @GoodSp33d Thanks!!! You solved my problem. Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks to @GoodSp33d. 
For those who are using Xcode 7. Please refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817873/366346).

Here is my updated code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your image url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```