# Xcode7 - WebView app black screen in simulator

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios-simulator, xcode7

I'm kinda new to xcode and I'm trying to make a webView app. In Android Studio I'm done in 10 minutes, but I've been struggling with a iOS one for a few days now. On build the app is not showing any errors or bugs, and the simulator works just fine. But when it tries to start my app, the screen turns black, but I'm still able to navigate just fine on the simulator phone so I think the app is the problem?

I have followed two different tutorials for making a webview app, but they both give the same result as mentioned before:

**Tutorial 1:** [iOS Tutorial – Creating a Web View (UIWebView)](http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/) 
**Tutorial 2:** [How To Make an App For Your Website In Less Than 30 Minutes](http://codewithchris.com/make-an-app-from-website/)
**Xcode version:** 7 
**Deployment target:** 8.4 
**Simulator tested**: iPhone 6s plus/iPhone 6s/iPhone 4s

Just followed **[another tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/webview-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift)**, and it seems to be working fine for apple.com, but not for the website that I want to use it for: http://macrofoods.nl
The app seems to be stuck at a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured it out. The last tutoriali posted works fine. Xcode/the app was blocking the website because it's not a https:// website, but a http:// website. To work around this, i stumbled on this question: [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

And i got my app working.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to build a cross platform app ..?
you can make hybrid apps with cordova/phonegap.it's running on a web interface.

[Check this](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/what_is_the_easiest_way_to_create_a_web_view_app_with_phonegap_build_and_jquery_mobile)

Comment: I've worked with Phonegap a little bit, but not with a remote website before, just local/offline :S