# Swift to php on local server doesn't work on my device?

Tags: ios, swift, post, swift2

I am having an issue with the following code, it works on the iphone 5s simulator. But when i attach my iphone5s device it doesn't work. With the simulator i get this (as expected) back from swiftupload.php

```
Button pressed <- swift
responseString = Optional({"message":"some variable"}Success) <- from php
Email has ben sent <- swift
```

And with my device attached i get

```
Button pressed
responseString = Optional()
```

The php file looks like:

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);

$message = $postdata["data"];

// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array("message" => $message);

// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

And this is the function in swift

```
    func postToServerFunction(){

    // json php
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/mydomain.com/swiftupload.php")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["data":"some variable"] as Dictionary<String, String>
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        //Response print

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200{
                print("Email has ben sent")
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()

    print("Button pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iPhone the **localhost** is IP of the iPhone.
Replace "**localhost**" with IP of your MAC/PC and check App Transport Security exceptions https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732693/4755417

Comment: But offcourse, thanks. I already made the "hacky" NSAppTransportSecurity