# App Transport Security issue iOS9

Tags: ios, plist, ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

After trying to run the app on the iOS9 simulator i've faced the following nasty warning

> The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security
>   policy requires the use of a secure connection.

After googling for solutions i've found one.
Opening your `project's .plist` file as a Source code and adding those lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Cleaned the build, ran - and saw similar warning.
Afterwards, I've tried a variety of other approaches listed here [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

None worked.

I tried allowing all domains even though it's a rejection-risk approach.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

it also didn't work. Seems like Xcode 7.0.1 is overriding this configuration no matter how i edit the `plist` file.

Looking forward to any advices on the subject.

Comment: Do not edit the plist file directly. Indeed Xcode could rewrite it. Use the `Info` tab (next to `Resource Tags`) in Xcode to create the new content in "Custom Application Target Properties".

Comment: "None worked" They _do_ work. You should assume that _you_ are the one not doing it properly.

Comment: I don't think you should set both the NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads and the NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy keys at the same time. Try just NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads.

Comment: @matt ok, i edit the plist file as source code, copy paste the solutions with my domain, re-open it as property list - everything works, i can see correct property types and boolean values at the very end of the plist. Unfortunately, when i run it - those rules just don't apply. what is more to it?

Comment: @GlennHowes tried it, same result ((

Comment: @EricD. tried, it didn't work... totally confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain name your are calling has which security version layer?

Apple default settings is 1.2 TLS. Your API may be on 1.1 or 1.0 security. Try to set the **NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion**. Just edit the dictionary in info.plist in which you mentioned your domain name. Here is an example for TLS version 1.0 security.

```
<key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
```