# Post request to server for get data , occur error : The resource could not be loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I use below code for get data from server with post request

```
NSString *serverUrl=@"http://192.168.1.105:2300/api/customer";
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=%@",actionName];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverUrl]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

but occur below error :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9be35f19a0

I find several post that says add below lines in info.plist and i added , but again i get error

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>http://192.168.1.105:2300</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

why ?

Comment: `your_domain_here`, did you replace this?

Comment: replace with : http://192.168.1.105:2300

Comment: Try with this `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>`

Comment: @anhtu : add it but again error

Comment: Try adding only a variable boolean to `NSAppTransportSecurity` named `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and set it to YES. (Although this is a work-around and the approach that you are using is the correct way to go about it)

Comment: @SajjadZare Remember, You should remove all other entries from `NSAppTransportSecurity` and have only one key-val in that dic. Which is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`. Works for me. It would look something like this: http://i.imgur.com/8HKxl7W.png

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing this error because your server uses `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: Thank youuuuu , solveeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Great. Glad to know that. You should accept @anhtu's answer if he posts it. He told you about this first.

Comment: @SajjadZare but using this one will have some risks.

Comment: @NSNoob so kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore all security restrictions like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But this isn't a good solution.

Ref [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 0):

For more information about **NSAppTransportSecurity** see the document on this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html
[image]

1. Step: Go to your project info as example (image is showing with
   green marked will show you after complete following steps).
2. Step: Add new property **NSAppTransportSecurity**  and Type will
   be **Dictionary** .
3. Step: Add Key **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** select property type
   Boolean and to set YES. And your code will run without any
   **NSAppTransportSecurity** exception .