# iOS 9 : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 on loading image from an URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, app-transport-security

I have two targets in my app , app was working fine till iOS 9 updates.

All of a sudden image loading began failing with error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “linkimagehandler.ashx” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http:la ..blw…RiS823e11rnf6dWjLasnjmiTYQpdDP+ZTekhIWBYx1PQfIUSDVJMT4dxE6VZ7YybIDRav0jKRLFa}
```

On searching I came to know about new network access security in iOS 9.

I got the clue of adding  following in both the plist files for bypassing :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

This solved my problem for target which i have added before few months.
But i still face the same issue in the target which was cerated along with project around 10 months ago.

I am missing anything here.

Please guide .

Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: What is the calling method to request this file ?

Comment: @Niko i think calling request is not the issue as images load fine in another target

Comment: I see in the message "UserInfo={NSURL=http:la ..blw " , is the url not http:// prefixed ?

Comment: @Niko here is the complete URL "http://SERVER_NAME_HERE/linkimagehandler.ashx?lid=lzjlgNdPQXn2BzSLl2HdRiS823e11rnf6dWjLasnjmiTYQpdDP+ZTekhIWBYx1PQfIUSDVJMT4dxE6VZ7YybIDRav0jKRLFa"

Comment: Try then with adding the "http://"