# Deep link to other app doesn't open even though UIApplication.sharedApplication.canOpenURL(url) returns true

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I followed this guide on [Twitter Dev Site](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes) in my app, Captions for Instagram, to set up the query scheme. It looks like this:
[image]

Then in my other app, I've added `captions` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and I am running the following code in that app:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "captions://")!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Using breakpoints, I found that `UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)` is returning true but `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)` is not doing anything.

Comment: must be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Does `openURL` run if you don't check for `canOpenURL` first? Are you using this only for behind-the-scenes communication between the two apps, or would the resulting `captions://` links ever be seen by the user? What if the receiving app isn't installed?

Comment: Yes it does run but still does nothing and if the `canOpenURL` fails I would present a `SKStoreProductViewController` with the app