# Wierd SSL problems with ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl

We have an issue with SSL since a few days ago.
Our APIs reside at amazon, and the app is calling the API via HTTPS.
For months it has been good, but since a few days we started getting:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot
>   be made.

Amazon says its nothing on their side. But we can't pinpoint on the issue, as this is happens sporadically and random countries, ios versions and models...

How can we understand where the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you disabled or allowed you connection to pass the App Transport Security. Also try using a different internet source, you might have something blocking your connection to the server.

Comment: You need to add App Transport Security Key in your info.plist file. Check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: We are whitelisting our APIs. This is really happening rarely but started appearing suddenly