# Firebase " firebase this page is trying load scripts from unauthenticated sources

Tags: ios, swift, google-chrome, firebase

was just working with firebase trying to add data from my application to firebase everything was going well. however when i try to log in to firebase dashboard it seems to just stay on the loading page and shield is displayed at the side of the address bar stating " firebase this page is trying load scripts from unauthenticated sources" i have check firebase's status on twitter there are no new posts. suggesting the problem is me, however it was completely fine a few hours ago.

very frustrating, anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you did what says [Firebase iOS SDK Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-login) for login process you can check these explanations [Source1](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en) [Source2](https://support.schoology.com/hc/en-us/articles/201002223--This-page-is-trying-to-load-scripts-from-unauthenticated-sources-Error-Load-Unsafe-Scripts-). I think that google chrome might be effected or`NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load` problem, make sure [Allow Arbitrary Loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) and then Product > Clean, Run again.