# cordova iframe "protocols must match" only on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, cors

Recently i was put in charge of updating the cordova framework (from 1.8 to 6.1) of a monolithic app, for both android and ios, the app is huge, but i just needed to update the cordova framework, after the complete update (including plugins) in the ios version of the app i found this error.

"The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'file'. Protocols must match."

on the android version there is no problem at all and everything is loaded fine

the config file already has the  access origin="*", allow-intent href="*",  and allow-navigation href="*". If someone here could point me the path to find whats happening, it will be great.

Comment: Try this, it sounds related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: no luck =(, the .plist already had the entry NSAllowArbitraryLoads, also tried other solutions in the comments, and its not working. thanks

Comment: can you share the markup code that's related to this error?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?