# Twitter user image Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform, nsurl

I'm trying to get user image from twitter(parse- twitter login)  using this code :

```
 if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {

        let screenName = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName!
        let requestString = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + screenName!)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestString!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
        PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.signRequest(request)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            print(data)
            print(response)
            print(error)

            if error == nil {
                var result: AnyObject?
                do {
                    result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                } catch let error2 as NSError? {
                    print("error 2 \(error2)")
                }

                let names: String! = result?.objectForKey("name") as! String
                let separatedNames: [String] = names.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

                //self.firstName = separatedNames.first!
                //self.lastName = separatedNames.last!

                let urlString = result?.objectForKey("profile_image_url_https") as! String
                let hiResUrlString = urlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_normal", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                let twitterPhotoUrl = NSURL(string: hiResUrlString)
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: twitterPhotoUrl!)
                let twitterImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                self.userImg = UIImageView(image: twitterImage)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

but it imageData is nil

```
  let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: twitterPhotoUrl!) 
  let twitterImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data:imageData!)
```

[twitterphotoUrl actually have the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awtx4.png)

any help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code,

```
if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: twitterPhotoUrl!)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.userImg.image = UIImage(image: imageData!)
     })
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: thank you , it did work , but do have any idea why does it take so long to load the image?

Comment: Obviously, directly assigning data to image it will take times. You can reduce time by assigning data in `async` method like : `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                   self.userImg.image = UIImage(image: imageData!)
                })`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you're getting an ATS exception from the `pbs.twimg.com` URL, so you're not getting the data, so you fall over when you force unwrap it. You should add that domain to the list of ATS exceptions as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9), [documented here] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) (search for NSExceptionDomain on that page) and discussed in many other places.

In addition to that, force unwrapping the results of URL calls is always a bad idea, since any number of things could prevent a data object being created. You should be using guard or if let statements in this case.

Comment: thank you , I did add this to info.plist file , and I no longer have a "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP" error now. but the image takes long time to show up!