# Image not appearing within ListView in a react native application

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-listview

I have a ListView which renders images.

```
<ListView
  renderRow={this.renderRow}
  dataSource={this.dataSource}
  pageSize={4}
  initialListSize={4}
  contentInset={{ bottom: 50 }}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
/>
```

The renderRow method renders the image as follows:

```
<View style={styles.itemSection}>
  <Image
    source={{ uri: card.image }}
    style={styles.itemImage}
    resizeMode="cover"
  />
</View>
```

The image is not getting rendered. Screenshot below:
[image]

Below embedding the image in a ListView, the images were getting rendered appropriately. Any pointers to get the image viewable within ListView?

Example of the image url is: http://s3.amazonaws.com/sendto.us/postcards/fronts/000/000/017/original/from_api.png?1471627160

Sharing the styles:

```
itemSection: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 30,
    paddingRight: 30,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  itemImage: {
    width: 120,
    height: 80,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#333',
  },
```

Comment: are you sure the image not a SVG?

Comment: it is png or jpg images.

Comment: share styles.itemImage and styles.itemSection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `info.plist`
[image]

Also, refer to

[How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)
and

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)