# Objective-C RSS Reader - XML reading error

Tags: objective-c, xml, rss-reader

I am new to obj-C and i'm trying to make an easy RSS Reader. It works with an external RSS file but not when i load the same file in my server based on AWS services.

This is the snippet code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

If i read that rss via web, i see this:
[image: original file]

When I upload that file on my server, i see this:
[image: uploaded file]

I tried to avoid manual upload via Filezilla but using wget command and i also tried ascii mode transfer, but still not work. RSS Reader show an empty list.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to AWS or Objective-C. But what you could do it read the two as NSString, and check if there are some differences. Also, are both pages ending with `.rss`?

Comment: Both pages ending with `.rss`. I used the same file from Apple.com. The original one works on my app, while the same file uploaded in my server not work :(

Comment: What's the error? Is `url` nil on the AWS's page?

Comment: RSS reader doesn't read the rss file on my server. I discovered many seconds ago the error is my server doesn't have https:// ... i've temporary place the file on the another server with ssl certificate and it works. In general xml parser can't read file from http domain?

Comment: App Transport Security Issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Yay! Now It works! Thaaaank you!!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem with URL. I had the crash with the same code with error

```
Unable to read data
```

I replaced code with

```
feedURL = NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.fuVEonEt.dpuf")!
parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:feedURL as URL)!
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse()
```

It work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Larme, it was the App Transport Security Issue [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) .

This solved my issue!