# How to store push notification token into external database - iOS 10, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i had implement FCM and i would like to send push notification from my own app server(written in PHP). Therefore, i would need to store the device token for fcm in my Phpmyadmin database. Is there a way to store the token into my database from iOS swift? would be appreciated if someone would give me some tips regarding this issue, thanks!

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)

}
```

**Database table structure:**

[image]

Comment: your code is fine , where your webservice code for send the token for server

Comment: Hi Anbu Karithik , i just created send POST request on iOS to server , is it the proper way to pass the token into my phpmyAdmin database ? Thanks for comment

Comment: 100 % correct , would you need the support for this

Comment: yes please and thanks you very much for your effort !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1**

> create the common method for access in two places

```
  func Callquery(_ token: String)   
 {

  // append parameter to oneDictionary
  let tokenString = ["keyName": token] as [String: Any]

   // create the request
  var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"yourServer URL")!)

  // set the method as POST
  request.httpMethod = "POST"

  // append the paramter to body
  request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tokenString, options: [])

// create the session
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        do {
            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                
            guard let errors = json?["errors"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
                if errors.count > 0 {
                    // show error
                    return
                } else {
                    // show confirmation
                }
            }
        }
    }).resume()
   }
```

**Step-2**

after **iOS9** we need to enble the **transport security** in out **.plist**, see this for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

**Step-3**

call method in two places

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
  print("Registration failed!")
  
    Callquery("") // pass the empty paramter if user deny the permission.
  
   }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    
    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)

      Callquery(token) // pass the token paramter if user accept the permission.
    
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much Anbu, it works like a charm in iOS 10 :) have a nice day

Comment: Hi Anbu, i realise the token string stored in my database table is always null , hope u could assist to look into this issue as well, i had post it as another question , you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994812/registration-token-stored-in-external-app-server-always-null-ios-10-swift-3