# POST data from iOS to php server always NULL - iOS 10, Swift 3, php

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

i am implementing a FCM app server and wanted to store the device registration token id into my own database (Server written in PHP).

I realise the data in device id token is always **null**, Can someone point the right way to store the token accordingly into database?

Really appreciated perhaps someone could guide me on this issue, thanks!

Kindly refer the code/screenshots below:-

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)
    Callquery(token)

}
```

**AppDelegate.swift (Callquery method which send a POST request to server side script)**

```
func Callquery(_ token: String)
{

    // append parameter to oneDictionary
    let tokenString = ["token": token] as [String: Any]

    // create the request
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://YourURL.com/admin/registerToken.php")!)

    // set the method as POST
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // append the paramter to body
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tokenString, options: [])

    // create the session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There was error during datatask session")
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else { return }

                guard let errors = json?["errors"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
                if errors.count > 0 {
                    // show error
                    print("There is an error during parse JSON datatask")
                    return
                } else {
                    // show confirmation
                    print("datatask with JSON format performed successfully")
                }
            }
        }
        print(request)
    }).resume()
}
```

**Service Side Script(registerToken.php):**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$token = $_POST['token'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email,device_id) VALUES ('email','$token')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Running App with real devices log as below:-**
[image]

**Database users table (device id always has nothing):-**
[image]

**users table structure:-**
[image]

**tokenString :-** 
[image]

Comment: sorry buddy I dont know php

Comment: is okie , thanks by the way :)

Comment: can you print this `tokenString`

Comment: okie i will edit once i had print the tokenString

Comment: @if reslut is comes , problem in saving on php code , else problem in here

Comment: had edited with token string shown , the token string did show a dictionary with token key with value.

Comment: then ios code is fine,check once in php side buddy

Comment: If you send this: yururl.php/token=123 from your browser, can you see it in DB?

Comment: @Rroobb tried just now and i can see it did executed a sql insert query but is null in device_id.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik okie , noted with thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had solved this issue by using GET method instead of POST method as below:-

**Appdelegate.swift :**

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://YourURL.com/admin/registerToken.php?token=\(token)")!)
```

**Server side script :**

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```