# image not showing from url of back4app.com(ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, back4app

I am using sd web image and  facing problem in getting image from back4app.com (parse server).
I have use below code with in main thread and without main thread.
And also try with encoding and without encoding.
I am getting another image from different url but from back4app.com not loading.

```
NSString *sttt2=flel.url;
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[sttt2 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [immg1 sd_setImageWithURL:url2  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilemain_blu"]];
            });
```

Comment: are you seeing the placeholder image ? Put a breakpoint in the setImageWithURL method and see what's happening there.

Comment: image not downloading

Comment: can u post the actual url ?

Comment: Try `NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:ulr2]`, Is `data` nil in this case? If not, if then you do `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];`, is `image` nil?

Comment: In nsdata  case it returns nil

Comment: Is `url2` nil? If `data` is `nil`, the issue is somewhere else, because your image is not available, nothing to do with `SDWebImage`, a server issue? Can you reach the image with the URL in a web browser? Do you need to add credential (password, tokens, etc.)?

Comment: https://parsefiles.back4app.com/PSzewrOeJEAci3sAncE1VUPl9L5ihRhdCoHJjJWB/33222324c600f45c3cfb27a70e14cca7_img.jpg

Comment: https://parsefiles.back4app.com/PSzewrOeJEAci3sAncE1VUPl9L5ihRhdCoHJjJWB/33222324c600f45c3cfb27a70e14cca7_img.jpg

This url hit on browser , i can  access on browser but not in app

Comment: url2 not nil but data is nil

Comment: And is `data` in `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];` nil? My guess: Do you have logs in Console that says that App Transport Security is blocking it? See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: I had already apply this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125706/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-larme).

Answer (score 0):

at Docs from Parse Server have a example to upload files, it's the code below:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];

PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
userPhoto[@"imageName"] = @"My trip to Hawaii!";
userPhoto[@"imageFile"] = imageFile;
[userPhoto saveInBackground];
```

Click here to read more: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#files

Other point to check, is the version that you're using, sometimes is related with some bug: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases