# Video Not playing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

In the following code:

```
// NSURL *videoURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"]];
NSURL *videoURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"]];



AVPlayer *playerV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = playerV;

[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [playerV play];
}];
```

VideoURL1 is working but videoURL2 is not working and the screen is like this:

[image: click here for screenshot]

I added keys and values in info.plist:

[image: Click here for screenshot]

Comment: Have you try MPMoviePlayerController...?

Comment: what is videoURL?

Comment: there should be videoURL2 i guess

Comment: @Sekhar just replace `AVPlayer *playerV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];` with `AVPlayer *playerV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL2];`

Comment: and it should be throwing you errors unless there is already some videoURL variable.

Comment: https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 #Syed

Comment: Its working in iOS 9 but not in iOS 10

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind not working you second url is that you are whitelisting only "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com" which does not support support secure connection. You should also whitelist "clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de" in the same manner you have whitelisted "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com" . If you are going to access video from many site dynamically which does not support secure connection(https) then  and the below line in your plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

For more detail have a look on following thread-

[How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

Comment: The second video uses HTTPS. So it doesn't need to be white-listed.

Comment: @codo2 - please write AVPlayer *playerV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: videoURL2]; instead AVPlayer *playerV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

Comment: Can anybody try the both video links to play, please provide code