# How to extract image from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, url, uiimageview

I am trying to extract an image from a url and place it in an image view.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/china-trump-sovereignity_us_5852000ee4b02edd4115d99b"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
_imageView.image = image;
```

How do I extract the image? (the url is only an example)

Comment: you need to download the image first then proceed.

Comment: are you getting any error like App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext in your debug window ?

Comment: you can use third party Library like `SDWebImage`, which will take care of image download.

Comment: the URL is not pointing to image, its a web page.

Comment: @suhit Have you see complete question including last line ?

Comment: I missed it somehow.

Comment: Turns out this line of code works: `NSString *string = @"http://efdreams.com/data_images/dreams/lion/lion-03.jpg";
    _imageURL.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]]];` But only if the url  strictly contains an image (like google images urls). How do I get an image from an article like the Washington post etc.? @suhit

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this Async Download:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURL *urlPic = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/china-trump-sovereignity_us_5852000ee4b02edd4115d99b"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPic cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeOutTime];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];                
            });
        } else {
           //Fail
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
```

Comment: This will work and no need to use any thir party classes like SDWebImageView and all.

Comment: Sure.... If we have something in native so why should we depend on third party library.

Comment: Make sense :) Up voting you

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = @"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/china-trump-sovereignity_us_5852000ee4b02edd4115d99b";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[self.imageview setImage:image];
```

Show image in Async mode,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/"];

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (data) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (image) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        imageView.image = image;
                });
            }
        }
    }];
```

Try this one.

Comment: There is no difference between your code and OP you have just add one more line with String url

Comment: This will block your UI until image gets download. Best way is to use lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Normal approach if don't wanted to go with Third Party Library

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);  
dispatch_async(queue, ^{  
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/china-trump-sovereignity_us_5852000ee4b02edd4115d99b"]];  
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];  
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
self.imageView.image = image;  
});  
});
```

but if you are not limited to use Third party Library i would personally suggest you to use [SDWebImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), This Library will help you to download image and cache it.

Answer (score 0):

First enable [App Transport Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) (ATS) as the URL is http. Then use NSURLSession API to download image

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/china-trump-sovereignity_us_5852000ee4b02edd4115d99b"];

typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

          if (error == nil) {
              UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                                          [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
              if (downloadedImage != nil) {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      weakSelf.imgView.image = downloadedImage;
                  });
              }
          }
 }];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, completeURLImage).response { (request, response, data, error) in
       yourImageView.image = nil
       yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1)
 }
```