# URLSession sends GET request instead of POST

Tags: ios, swift, http, urlrequest, urlsession

That's how I'm doing a POST request

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let methodString = mehtod.rawValue
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

if let headers = headers {
    request.set(headers: headers)
}

if let parameters = parameters {
    do {
        let postParams =  try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
        let postData = postParams
        request.httpBody = postData
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }
}

let session = URLSession.shared

print(request)
print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
print(String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)!)
print(request.httpMethod)

session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    let result: Result<Data>

    if let data = data {
        result = .success(data)
    }
    else if let error = error {
        result = .failure(error)
    }
    else {
        result = .failure(RESTError.unknownError)
    }

    completion(result)

    }.resume()
```

And this is what I see in Charles

[image]

I'm trying to send POST but somehow I'm sending GET request.
Also I'm getting error from the server:

```
{"message":"Method \"GET\" not allowed.","code":"method_not_allowed"}
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997641/how-to-make-nsurlsession-post-request-in-swift

Comment: Have you checked that `parameters` Is not  `nil`

Comment: @Paulw11 yep, it's not nil

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When redirect occurs iOS makes new request and change POST to GET. Also your body became empty.
Double check if you're by accident using http instead https.

You can also implement
(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)redirectResponse newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler

but for me that wasn't solution.

Here is more details
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/12749?answerId=34834022#34834022

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `session.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData)`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your post string as dictionary than convert it to jason string.
if you have problem converting your data to jason tell me i ill give you a method for it.

```
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

  let paramString = yourPostDataInJASON!
  print(paramString)
  request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```