# Issue Sending Params and Parsing Results | Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I currently have the following JSON parsing function that is meant to send  Params, Parse the response and then display the value of the JSON code string in the textfield.

I am having some issues understanding how params can be implemented into this function.

```
class A: Codable {
    var code: String?
    var position: String?
    var person: String?
}



 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "example.com/example")!)
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
 URLSession(configuration: .default)
     .dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
         if let error = error {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 failure(error)
             }
             return
         } else if let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode(A.self, from: data) {

              exampleTextField.text = model.code
         }
    }
```

JSON Response that is sent when the proper params are sent:

```
{
    "code": "WE3049320",
    "position": "Instructor",
    "person": "Jeff"
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors? Can you show us the `JSON`?

Comment: This is not alomofire

Comment: I have posted the JSON response.

Comment: @MarkPalson Currently what parameters are you sending?

Comment: @KeshuR. My apologies I did not mean to put Alamofire, I was using it somewhere else

Comment: @MarkPalson here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520837/8374890

Comment: I need to send params "department" and "facility"; department equals "DEP1" and facility = "FAC1"

Comment: @KeshuR. I don't believe he is parsing the response, I need to take response after the POST and assign the value to a textfield

Comment: you want to try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148)

Comment: I don't see `.resume()` for `URLSession`. Did you use it?

Comment: @Rob is it possible to POST then Parse and assign the response?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev I did not .resume how can this be implemented