# Not able to send post request using URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift4, urlsession

I am trying to send post request through `URLSession`

I am constructing my payload using this

```
let params: [String : Any] = [
                "name": username,
                "password": password,
                "email": email,
                "c_password": confirmPassword
            ]
```

also with this

```
var urlParser = URLComponents()
            urlParser.queryItems = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: username),
                URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: password),
                URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: email),
                URLQueryItem(name: "c_password", value: confirmPassword)
            ]
```

and this setting it to httpBody like this

```
 request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
```

and calling my function but it throws me the error

`The request was well formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors`

But when I try to send request in this way

`let parameters = "name=test&password=Pass@123&c_password=Pass@123&email=test111@gmail.com"`

it works

but when I try to make it dynamic

`let parameters  = "name=\(username)&password=\(password)&c_password=\(confirmPassword)&email=\(email)"`

it gives me error.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Complete code

```
if let url = URL(string: Constants.REGISTRATION_URL){
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let params: [String : Any] = [
                "name": username,
                "password": password,
                "email": email,
                "c_password": confirmPassword
            ]
            var urlParser = URLComponents()
            urlParser.queryItems = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: username),
                URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: password),
                URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: email),
                URLQueryItem(name: "c_password", value: confirmPassword)
            ]
          //  let httpBodyString = urlParser.percentEncodedQuery
           // let parameters = "name=test&password=Pass@123&c_password=Pass@123&email=test111@gmail.com"
            let parameters  = "name=\(username)&password=\(password)&c_password=\(confirmPassword)&email=\(email)"
          
            request.addValue("Application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
             request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
            APIManager.sharedInstance.postCall(request: request, onSuccess: { json in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    
                }
            }, onFailure: { error in
                do{
                    let errorModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorModel.self, from: Data(error.utf8))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showAlertMessage(alertMessage: errorModel.errors[0].detail)
                    }
                }catch{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showAlertMessage(alertMessage: error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Would you need to escape some characters? Did you checked the output you send in your different tests: `let bodyString = String(data: request.httpBody, encoding: .utf8)` and compare?

Comment: @Larme  yes I checked the output before sending it, all are same

Comment: @Larme the output is same

`1- "name=test&password=Pass@123&c_password=Pass@123&email=test111@gmail.com"
"2- name=test&password=Test@123&email=test@dvt.com&c_password=Test@123"
"3- 
name=test&password=Test%40123&c_password=Test%40123&email=test%40dvt.com"`

Comment: "%40", here there is a percent escape for the `@` Normal on "2" and "3".

Comment: it is encoding the `@` character  which is fine, but anyway even the 2nd one is also not working

Comment: For which one is it working? 1, 2, or 3? Because that percent escaping @ was one difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222790/discussion-between-rigsby-and-larme).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're attempting to send a GET query string to a POST request.

GET requests expect a character escaped string (like what you have).

POST requests expect (mostly )a dictionary object (like your param dictionary)

[See this answer for how to set a POST request properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520837/264273)

Comment: There is other parameter encoding than JSON. Like `x-www-form-urlencoded`, XML, etc.

Comment: when i try sending dictionary object it throws error

Comment: error is resolve, seems its backend issue, with specific type of domain.