# Simulate URL Loading System Error Codes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Users of an app I took over recently are reporting network error alerts like those:

> Network error (-1009)
>
> Network error (-1001)
>
> Network error (-1005)
>
> Network error (2)

[image]

(Fejl is Danish for Error)

The error are: `NSURLErrorTimedOut`, `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`, `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`, so mostly about bad/lost connection to the server.

`AFNetworking 3.0` is used.

In the request headers we find `Connection: close` and the timeout is set to 15 seconds `request.timeoutInterval = 30`

First, I couldn't find showing an alert anywhere in the source code, so I would like to know if the displayed alerts on network errors are handled by iOS?

Then, I am looking for a way to simulate those errors. I tried with the Network Link Conditioner on a device but didn't get any of those errors.

The errors and their respective error codes are listed here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes?language=objc

Comment: iOS never shows network alerts on its own, until it is defined somewhere. Are you using any third party library? I guess it might be coming from there. By the way you need to add [App Transport Security](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817873/790842) that might be missing and causing the error.

Comment: Yes, AFNetworking 3.0 is used in the project.

Comment: But one comment says that the [NSAppTransportSecurity key is no longer accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9/32817873#comment64811499_32817873)

Comment: You still need to add it the only thing changed is the url must be `https`

Comment: But if I enable NSAllowsArbitraryLoads wouldn't that allow unsecured connections? I am using HTTPS connections to dev, staging and production servers, so maybe the issue is not there?