# Webkit (swift) doesn't open any pages

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

i can't open all pages in my project, for example:

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.dreambox.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
    self.myWebView.mainFrame.load(requestObj as URLRequest!);
```

But i can open sites like google and wikipedia

```
let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
    self.myWebView.mainFrame.load(requestObj as URLRequest!);
```

Comment: This could be the case because Apple requires HTTPS to be used. You can however add exceptions for unencrypted sites. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/></dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let add these keys into the Info.plist

[image]

Comment: Which keys?........