# My test run iPad don't connect to my RESTApi server

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development, I finally make my app work on the simulator device, I can send POST & GET to my Node.JS server and and work as what I'm expected.

Now the problem is, while I try to test run on my iPad, no POST and GET request being sent, is this a restriction for test run on my own device?

Comment: Perhaps your server has http endpoints which won't work by default (opposed to https) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Hi Kamil.S, but my simulator device is working fine. I already add on exception in my info.plist as my server is http.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, my url to my Node server was put http://localhost.

So I change it to IP address and it's working fine now.