# Assign an image from a URL to an image view in a collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this method to assign a YouTube video thumbnail to an image view in a custom collection cell view:

```
  [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:youtubeImageString]
                  placeholderImage:nil
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                             if (cacheType != SDImageCacheTypeMemory)
                             {
                                 cell.imageView.alpha = 0.0;
                                 double val = ((double)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX)*0.8;
                                 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:val options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                     cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                 } completion:nil];
                             }
                         }];
```

When I build and run my application, I'll get an empty cell. I have debugged the code with break points, and the URL is correct and the JSON data is there, but the images are not showing.

[image: Debugging]

Comment: "the url is correct " : What's the value of `[NSURL URLWithString:youtubeImageString]`? Did you read the `error` param of the block?

Comment: @Larme that's the value: http://img.youtube.com/vi/8e0jlmHVUyY/hqdefault.jpg and what do you mean by "read the error param of the block?"

Comment: The the `completed` block, is error nil? You did only `if (cacheType != SDImageCacheTypeMemory)`, but is `error` nil there? Is your issue only related to the animation? If you remove the animation, does it work?

Comment: @Larme no it's not nil, it gives me an NSURLErrorDomain: NSError NSError domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550594 and no even if I remove the animation still doesn't show any images.

Comment: @Larme could it be because it's a http url ?

Comment: @TahaAmini, I think you have to add some AppTransport Security setting in your App in order to access image using URL. Please go through the below url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: @Prakash yup it's working now , thanks !

Comment: @TahaAmini, PLease accept my anwser if it has solved your issue.

Comment: @Prakash okay, write it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Larme thank you for your help also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add exceptions for specific domains in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```