# ReactNative - axios - http request to get xml feed

Tags: xml, reactjs, react-native, axios

The JSON response works as expected

```
axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => console.log(response))
```

Not able to get response may be because it's XML?

```
axios.get('http://thefederalistpapers.org/feed')
      .then(response => console.log(response))
```

Does axios work to fetch XML feed?

Here is the error I am getting:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Error: Network Error

Basically what I am trying to do is, get the XML from HTTP request and I am not sure how to convert it to JSON

I even tried this [react-native-xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-xml2js) but did not help because it doesn't support async, not sure.

> async (default false): Should the callbacks be async? This might be an
>   incompatible change if your code depends on sync execution of
>   callbacks. Future versions of xml2js might change this default, so the
>   recommendation is to not depend on sync execution anyway. Added in
>   0.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

[ios-app-transport-security-and-loading-http-resources](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.28/docs/known-issues.html#ios-app-transport-security-and-loading-http-resources)

this is known issue in react native iOS it dose not allow http protocol only https unless you made an exception in info.plist

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9/30732693#30732693](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007661/7149898)

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
axios.get('linkgoeshere', { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Dont know exactly but try it I guess.