# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

Tags: xcode, nsurlconnection, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios11

Friends i have simple audio player (MPMoviePlayerController) which can play audio stream. On iOS 11 i have very interessing trouble, thousand time i have error and my stream was stopped:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
```

I paste this code (this code i saw on stackowerflow) but it's not help to me:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>cast.mysite.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Maybe you know best solution?

Comment: Make sure you are streaming audio from secure server (server with valid certificate).

Comment: it's obligation? i have 8 http stream's and on iOS 10 work perfectly but on iOS 11 - after 5 minutes player stop

Comment: I answered your concern in "Answer" section because in comment area it is difficult to address your issue.

Comment: Thanks man, but i have audio stream and how i know audio stream it's not necessary to use https..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That error should *not* be related to using HTTP instead of HTTPS.  App Transport Security failures return error code -1022.

The error code -1002 indicates an invalid URL.  Perhaps your HTTP live streaming playlist file contains a structurally invalid URL (e.g. missing scheme, a scheme other than http/https, etc.)?

For additional debugging, set this environment variable

```
CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS=1
```

in your Xcode project and re-run the app.  Once you know what URL is failing, the problem will likely become more obvious.

If it isn't, file a bug.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: tic read status [58:0x0]: 1:57 i know very well that it's not error but very annoying every time before start show this line

Comment: You might try adding `<key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key><false/>` to your per-domain exception.

Comment: It's possible to send me screen how look like this line, because i am not understand. Thanks. It will be very advisable for all who follow  my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Anyway i have million  TIC Read Status [10:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: But anyway new Xcode very annoying with new issues TIC and it's not only my opinion, just look AppStore rating of new Xcode version...

Comment: Nothing to do with Xcode.  It's additional debugging in that version of iOS (and, by extension, the simulator).

Comment: I have used it, but I didn't get any useful info

Comment: CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS gives details on network failure

Answer (score 1):

This issue can appear if your URL contains spaces. I solved it by replacing the spaces with "%20", and then you can use it safely. The Objective C code to replace the spaces is below.

```
your_url_variable_name = [your_url_variable_name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Comment: No, my URL don't have no one space. Like this site.com/blabla.json

Comment: Any illegal character should cause the NSURL to be nil, so if you can create an NSURL from it successfully, it shouldn't be an illegal character issue, and if you can't, well then there's your problem.  :)

Answer (score -2):

First thing you must use secure server (server with valid certificate).
I'm not sure either it is necessary or not because i never tried to hit server with invalid certificate. You can try this code (not sure it will work for you or not) put this code in Appdelegate.m

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: I will try this after 2-3 days and answer, if it's ok i will accept your answer, but anyway thanks!

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea.  This disables all URL request security for your entire app, and your app will be rejected from the iOS App Store if you try it.