# Unable to load link in webview

Tags: swift, xcode, web, webview, cloudflare

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webvw: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webvw.load(request)
```

Edit: (Replace example with profittneshc) The website will not open in a mac or iOS app... I'm not sure why!

Comment: Im assuming that its a website issue as I can load most other websites. I'm baffled as to what to tell them though.

Comment: Make sure that domain is allowed in your `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)