# How can I play video in Swift 4 remotely with playerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9.2

It shows my just like this:

[image]

```
  let myURL = "http://example.come/package=07e9a825-7be4-4ce7-8a6ec78b"
    let videoURL = URL(string: myURL)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
```

> but when I use the URL in my browser it's completely ok with that mp4 video. what I miss?

Comment: Have you checked [App Transport Security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007661/988169)

Comment: Every time someone uses force-unwrapping my soul dies bit by bit

Comment: I add Allow Arbitrary Loads for App Transport Security Settings , should I do more?

Comment: More info is necessary. When you play the item, check `player.currentItem.status` and if it is `failed`, check `player.currentItem.error` for description why did your asset fail to play

Comment: @mag_zbc first of all sorry for ur soul :), it talks lot's of death soul to someone can step forward , and after that thanks for ur help, it says AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 and apparently the problem comes from server.

Comment: I have the same problem - can you somehow workaround this on the device because I cannot change the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Inside the info.plist file, insert the lines 
and the problem should be solved