# Why won't my iOS beta app connect to network / internet?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight

I'm facing a weird problem.

While I was testing my app on xCode, everything was working like a charm, even internet accessing.

I uploaded my build to Testflight and my testers won't be able to connect.

Even more surprising : I realize that the one I'm using on my phone is the xCode build, not installed via testflight, and still wont be able to access the internet while it was perfectly able to do so while connected to xCode...

EDIT : tested my web service which works as well

Did any one of you already face this problem ? How should I solve this ?

Thanks very much in advance

Vincent

Comment: Is your backend accessible from outside of your internal network? Are you facing this issues on WiFi or on mobile networks? Do other apps on these devices work fine?

Comment: Does your web service use `http` or secure `https`

Comment: @Losiowaty My backend is on an online web server. I can access it from safari on the same device. I only tested on cellular network but my testers all reported the same problem both on wifi and cellular networks.

Comment: @Ladislav Only http

Comment: So by default `iOS` will not allow `http` connections because of `App Transport Security`, so did you enable `http` access to your webservice in the app? - Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: @Ladislav I'll give this a try. I had this idea as well but how comes that it will work whiled deployed with xCode and connected to the mac ?  ?

Comment: I would expect it not to work anywhere you are correct, but it is worth a try...you can also make a call to a test `https` webservice and see if you get a response there...

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give it a try ASAP :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,

I Had a deeper look into it after @Ladislav and @Losiowaty suggestions.
The problem was actually elsewere. The app behavior was like if there was a network problem. I didn't remember about it but I changed one line in the returned jSon use, which caused a non fatal error and the results not showing, which couldn't be seen without reading logs.

Thank you all for your time anyway !