# Alamofire ignoring closure that sets/handles data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to perform a network request to the dummy data source https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and render it in my application.

I have a file called `NetworkingClient.swift` that abstracts most of this logic out and allows is to be reused.

```
public class NetworkingClient {
    typealias WebServiceResponse = ([[String: Any]]?, Error?) -> Void

    func execute(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping WebServiceResponse) {
        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            if let error = response.error {
                completion(nil, error)
            } else if let jsonArray = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
                completion(jsonArray, nil)
            } else if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion([jsonDict], nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call the `execute` in a set up function I have in my main view controller file:

```
func setUpView() {
        let networkingClient = NetworkingClient()
        let posts_endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        let posts_endpoint_url = URL(string: TEST_URL_STRING)
        networkingClient.execute(posts_endpoint_url) { (json, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print([["error": error]])
            } else if let json = json {
                print(json)
            }
        }
}
```

Where I call this inside `viewDidLoad()` under `super.viewDidLoad()`

I've set breakpoints inside the `response in` closure and I wasn't able to trigger any of them, in fact I think it's skipping the entire thing completely and I don't know why.

I am following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hcHbhIWIeI&t=869s) where the video guide does the exact same thing except their request goes through.

What am I missing?

I am using Swift 4, XCode 10, running on iOS 12.1 and my AlamoFire version is `4.7`.

Comment: Is App Transport Security Enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9 Also `let networkingClient = NetworkingClient()` is a local instance, it might be deallocate too soon. Try with either setting a property to your ViewController class, or by using for `NetworkingClient` Class method (since it might not be important to have instances).

Comment: @Larme I originally tried having `execute` as a class method and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about async stuff.your are declaring `NetworkingClient` object in func called `setupView` and Alamofire using `.background` thread to do stuff.so time executing of `networkingClient.execute` is not clear and after that `setUpView` deallocate from memory and all it's objects are gone including `NetworkingClient`.so for preventing this just declare `let networkingClient = NetworkingClient()` outside of function

Comment: Wouldn't having `execute` as a class function have the same effect? Because that didn't work either.

Comment: yes it has the same effect. you have to create that object outside of function.or using `Singleton` pattern to always have that object in memory