# Subscription not working in React Native?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I need to integrate `subscription` in my `ReactNative` app. The `subscription` works fine on `localhost` in `graphiql`. I have deployed my backend on `Heroku`. I am using `apollo-server` and not `hasura`. My subscriptions are not working for the url given by Heroku but it works fine on localhost. Queries and mutations work fine for both localhost and Heroku url. So I am trying to access my subscription from my `ReactNative` client. I have kept the base url as my local host. The queries and mutations part works for my `ReactNative` client but my subscription part is not working.

I have configured my Apollo client for subscription by adding this

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:5000',
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:5000`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      // headers: {
      //   Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      // },
    },
  },
});

const authLink = setContext(async (req, {headers}) => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});

const link = split(
  ({query}) => {
    const {kind, operation} = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink),
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Here is my `useSubscription` hook

```
const {data, error, loading} = useSubscription(
    HEALTH_CONSULTATION_SUBSCRIPTION,
  );
```

I am neither getting error nor data.
I am triggering the `subscription` from `Graphiql`

Comment: is the url you are triyng to connect wss or https? If it is a domain and not a localhost you have to add a secure transport exception for ios and android:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: @DanielDimitrov I have added it for iOS in info plist file. I have tried on https as well as localhost but does not work. I tried replacing https with ws , still it won't work. Also its ws and not was. Also my mutation and query are working so its not a transport issue

Comment: So what is the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: @DanielDimitrov I don't see anything no failure no success

Comment: Where are you looking? Do you see the request dispatching in the network inspect? Do you get a response? Maybe remove the try/catch block and see if you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was no problem from my `React Native` Code. The issue was with the free tier of Heroku I am using. I tried replacing my `subscription` with `Hasura's Subscription` `https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/graphiql?tutorial=react-native` and it works.