# Can't play HEVC with VideoPlayer on iOS 14 (emulator and device)

Tags: ios, avplayer, h.264, http-live-streaming, hevc

I'm making an app which will play live video from TV channels. Some channels are in HEVC format and some in h.264. H.264 plays just fine, but HEVC won't. I tried both on real device (iPhone 6s and iPhone 8 with iOS 14) and on emulator (iPhone 8, 11, 12 with iOS 14). I read on the internet, that only iPhones 7 and up support HEVC, so it's no surprise, that it doesn't work on iphone 6s.
Live stream is provided with HLS over HTTPS. HEVC and h.264 plays in VLC (Media -> Open Network Stream) so it shouldn't be an issue with stream.
Since I can't provide url of stream (internal use only), I will provide screenshot from VLC.
This is what url looks like: https://domain.example.com/api/stream/some_token/10
And after connection is established it redirects to: http://1xx.xx.xx.xx:85/stream/some_token/stream.m3u8
I allowed HTTP in Info.plist (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817873/4798218)

#### **Working h.264 stream codec info**

[image: Working H.264 Codec info]

[image: Working H.264 statistics]

### **Not working HEVC stream codec info**

[image: Not working HEVC Codec info]
[image: Not working HEVC statistics]

Now the code with which I'm trying to make it work. I tried it in AVPlayerVideoController and also with VideoPlayer (from AVKit, ios14+) and none play HEVC.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct SUIVideoPlayer: View {
    private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://domain.example.com/api/stream/some_token/10")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .onAppear() {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear() {
                player.pause()
            }
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any errors when trying to play HEVC or h.264 stream. One works, other one does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. TS files are not and will not be supported on iOS. You must use fMP4.
Official response from apple in their forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132291