# image uploading : http://inveera.biz/lowkall_api/index.php/img parameter is:id,name,file (With Afnetworking)

Tags: ios, afnetworking

```
NSString *strurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://inveera.biz/lowkall_api/index.php/img"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
// NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"];
//[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.loginId integerValue]] forKey:@"id"];
[parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginId"] integerValue]] forKey:@"id"];
[parameters setValue:selling.text forKey:@"name"];
[parameters setValue:@"image.jpg" forKey:@"file"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:strurl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSDictionary*    data1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", data1);
        //[Utils stopActivityIndicatorInView:self.view];
     UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation" message:@"User Registered Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alrt show];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     //[Utils stopActivityIndicatorInView:self.view];
     UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alrt show];

}];
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: What are you asking ?and please describe your issue...

Comment: Sir Actually I am Asking This is My Code And Not Properly Add Image With Image Path Code Is Crash And Parameter Goes To Null (From LoginId) Resopnse Please Give Correct suggestion And I am Using Afnetworking I am Not getting Plaese Shere Me And help me

Comment: possible duplicate [post data to PHP script from iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589255/post-data-to-php-script-from-ios)

Comment: Acttually i have already used in my app afnetworking....I am new Please Can U send me the demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://inveera.biz/lowkall_api/index.php/img"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.loginId integerValue]] forKey:@"id"];
[parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginId"] integerValue]] forKey:@"id"];
[parameters setValue:selling.text forKey:@"name"];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:strurl parameters:parameters  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {
     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YOUR_IMAGE_HERE, 0.5); // put your UIImage

     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSDictionary*    data1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", data1);
    //[Utils stopActivityIndicatorInView:self.view];
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation" message:@"User Registered Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alrt show];
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    //[Utils stopActivityIndicatorInView:self.view];
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alrt show];

}];
```

I have added block for image uploading, you can not directly upload the image via dictionary.

Please try this. hope this helps

**I have got this response when run the code**

```
{
    "p_id" = 69;
    status = true;
}
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: body' Show this   I am Not Getting

Comment: please see edited answer... i have put the response that i got from server while run the above code successfully.

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YOUR_IMAGE_HERE, 0.5); is your image is nil here....?. when this image is nil then the error occurs.

Comment: So what Will Be The solution

Comment: I think i have to set image path or image  UIImage *image  = [[UIImage alloc] init]; //your image here
          NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

Comment: From Method of - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info crash my course

Comment: will u please explain.... i am not getting   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init]; //your image here NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info this method

Comment: did you got the image from above method? then pass this image to "NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)" line. create UIImage variable at top and use it in this view controller. nad remove thiss line "UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];"